# An acknowledgements section thanking people you don't know

Tags: legal, book, acknowledgements

Acknowledgements sections that thank people you don't know and from whom you haven't asked permission are rare.

What are the pros and cons of including such thanks?

I suspect one of the reasons they're rare may be an assumption by editors and agents, passed on to authors, that if you thank a person you may reasonably be thought to be implying that they "endorse" your work. And if they haven't endorsed it, thanking them may make their lawyers feel either that you're leeching off of their reputation, viewed as their intellectual property, or that you're competing with it or even damaging it. So publishing houses play it safe.

But if you were to thank, shall we say, President A or professor B of country X for his wonderful inspiration, or President C or professor D of country Y for being the insufferable fool who finally caused you to want to tell your story, or to realise how things actually were...well, depending on circumstances, that might possibly be a more commercially sensible action than choosing the safety of not referring to the President or professor at all.

I have no idea what legal precedents there are. But a person may have inspired you who wouldn't be especially pleased about it if they found out. And a person may have stimulated you by what in your opinion are negative characteristics of their work. And in neither case are you necessarily breaking a law or committing a tort if you tell people, or if you tell 10 million people.

So my question is:

### what are the advantages and disadvantages of thanking a person in your acknowledgements section whom you don't know and whom you haven't told about your book or asked for permission?

This includes both the case of a living person and the case of a person who is no longer living.

Notes

1. I tried to add the tags `acknowledgements` and `front-matter` but couldn't, because I have insufficient status here. A moderator or editor who does possess the status may feel that one or both of these tags would be appropriate.
2. If this question would be better on law.SE, please advise - or transfer it there. Many thanks.

Comment: A lot depends on who you're thanking (and what for). It would be reasonable to thank a teacher, relative, employee, lawyer, etc, even if you didn't specifically mention it to them. And conversely if you thank Barack Obama, Taylor Swift, and Jesus, few people are going to think they were directly involved in the book. As one example, you talk about thanking a professor, but is this someone deeply involved in the same specific field, or someone from an unrelated area who acted as e.g. a childhood role model or more distant inspiration, or someone on the level of Feynman, Hawking, etc?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of acknowlegements in a book is

- to thank those who have made a specific effort to help your book come about and
- to acknowledge any sources you may have used.

You can therefore reveal in your acknowledgments that you have been inspired to write your book by the life of a real person, but for me it would seem utterly strange if you *thanked* them for it.

---

I would like to point out that if you admit that your story is based on real events or a character in your book is based on a real person, you might be infringing on certain of their rights (such as personality rights) or get sued for libel or defamation. So be careful with what you say about whom in your acknowledgements and who you connect your story with.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think it's probably OK legally to say something like "Thank you, A, for making me even clearer about the merits of X", whether this is meant in praise or in criticism of A. Where is the possible tort? It would even be possible to put a footnote referencing the work by A (not necessarily written) that has made you clearer about X. The acknowledgement would be similar to a review. Nobody does this, but that may be down to publisher conservatism. Personality rights are where there's possibly a question mark, I think.

Comment: @tell I'm not a lawyer and cannot judge the finer points of your case. My counter question would rather be, why do you even feel the need to acknowledge this?

Comment: To interest the reader ("This author has been influenced by A? What's that all about?") and to draw their active attention ("Never seen this kind of thing in an acknowledgements section before").

Comment: @tell That makes sense and is a valid reason. I think I have said everything there is to say in my answer.

Comment: It's common to include a disclaimer like "Thanks to X, Y, and Z for all their help, but any errors in the book are my fault alone."